# Extend space of vg00 / lv01 - ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, disk-usage

I try to extend my partition to use all the space on available on my disk (I'm working on a VPS server).

Here is the result of lsblk command:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0   80G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0  487M  0 part /boot
└─sda2          8:2    0 79.5G  0 part
  ├─vg00-lv00 253:0    0  1.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─vg00-lv01 253:1    0  7.6G  0 lvm  /
sr0            11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

As you can see, I have 79.5Go in sda2. I need to get them in vg00-lv01 , which is actually full (7.6Go / 7.6Go), without erase everything I have in this partition, just extend.

I'm a rookie to ubuntu and don't know how to achieve this. Anyone can help me on this one ?

doing resize2fs /dev/vg00/lv01 give me this output : *The filesystem is already 1995776 blocks long, nothing to do !*

Thank you !